# Combining tables where some keys are in common and some are missing

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have a table of landcover values in my postgres db (version 9.3). The key values are "huc12code", which represent a spatial area.  This is the first entry of the landcover table (it has 1700+ rows):

```
 huc12code   | open_water  |  developed  | bare_earth  |  managed | heritage
030402080205 |    0.107027 |   0.0215444 |    0.406911 |          |
```

The area of managed and heritage land is empty in this table but are stored in separate tables. They also have `huc12code` as the first column:

From the `temp_heritage` table:

```
 huc12code   |  heritage
-------------+-------------
030101020801 |   0.0402684
```

From  `temp_managed` table:

```
 huc12code   |   managed
-------------+------------- 
030101020802 | 0.000385026
```

I'd like to incorporate the managed & heritage fields into my landcover table, but I see two problems:

1. Most of the `huc12code` fields in the `landcover` table are found in `temp_managed` and `temp_heritage`, but some are not.  This is because the "temp" tables don't include places where the `heritage` and `managed` fields equal 0.
2. I do want the `landcover` table to include a 0 value where the `heritage` and `managed` fields are 0, but since these values aren't actually present in the "temp" tables, I need some logic that inserts a zero for the `heritage` field for each `huc12code` that is found in `landcover` but not in `temp_heritage` (and the same for the manage field).

Comment: So do left outer joins and then use COALESCE to replace nulls in those columns with default values (zeros or whatever).

Comment: This seems to work to query the column that I want to insert:  SELECT coalesce(temp_heritage.heritage,0) FROM landcover LEFT JOIN temp_heritage ON landcover.huc12code = temp_heritage.huc12code;

Comment: How do you combine the INSERT INTO command so that the results are inserted into landcover?  I haven't had much experience with that command and I don't want to screw up my landcover table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `huc12code` to be *unique* in all tables.

#### Only update rows where values are available

To do it all in a single `UPDATE` join the two source tables with a [`FULL [OUTER] JOIN`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-FROM) to preserve all rows. Then use this in the `FROM` clause of the [`UPDATE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html) command:

```
UPDATE landcover l
SET    managed  = COALESCE(t.managed, 0) 
     , heritage = COALESCE(t.heritage, 0) 
FROM (
   SELECT huc12code, m.managed, h.heritage
   FROM   temp_managed m
   FULL   JOIN temp_heritage h USING (huc12code)
   ) t
WHERE l.huc12code = t.huc12code;
```

Every row in `landcover` is updated **exactly one time** if there is a (combined) row in the source. The rest is not touched at all.

#### Update ***all*** rows

Use two `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
UPDATE landcover l
SET    managed  = COALESCE(t.managed, 0) 
     , heritage = COALESCE(t.heritage, 0) 
FROM (
   SELECT l.huc12code, m.managed, h.heritage
   FROM   landcover l
   LEFT   JOIN temp_managed  m USING (huc12code)
   LEFT   JOIN temp_heritage h USING (huc12code)
   ) t
WHERE l.huc12code = t.huc12code;
```

Columns without a source or source NULL value are set to `0`.

Comment: That didn't quite work.... The command didn't issue an error (it just stated: UPDATE 1620).  But the heritage and managed fields in landcover are still  empty

Comment: Actually, scratch that.  Those columns aren't completely empty.  They have long sections that are empty, then long sections of zeros and long sections with actual data.  I'm going to drop this table and then re-create my original landcover table.

Comment: @MeganMallard: That would not be a problem. Just define if you want to keep or update existing values in `landcover`.

Comment: The update all rows solution worked.  Thanks for your help!